# Get a Session variable's value that was set in Open SSO inside a ColdFusion App

Tags: session, coldfusion, opensso

We have a session variable that is set in the Open SSO application when the user logs in. I need to access this variable from a ColdFusion application. Is there any way to do it? I've tried GetPageContext().getSession() but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution! Turns out, the value was not in the session, but in the request header.

```
GetHTTPRequestData().headers['sessionvariablename']
```

Works for me.